# Component should only get painted once

Tags: delphi, components, paint, invalidation

I am creating my own component in Delphi 6
The component is working perfectly except for the paint section
my paint section starts like this

```
inherited Paint;
if (csdesigning in ComponentState) then
begin
```

so when the component is created at runtime it never get painted, but if I remove that line
it seems to get repainted all the time

is there a way I can move the (paint) code so it only get called on eg.  Invalidate

any would be a appreciated and in advance I thank you

Comment: People still use Delphi 6? Its like Windows 98 stuff.

Comment: No, invalidate causes the same painting code to run. Looks like the code in your paint handler itself is causing invalidation - which you should avoid.

Comment: @Havenard: I still use BCB6 in my day job.

Comment: You've provided no information except three lines of code totally out of context. It's extremely difficult to diagnose your problem based on that, other than to say that you need to fix the code that's causing your component to be invalidated and causing the Paint method to be called.

Comment: With the `if (csdesigning in ComponentState) then` statement you're telling the block should be executed only when the control is in design mode, so when the form is being designed in the IDE. You probably meant to write `if not (csdesigning in ComponentState) then`.

Answer (score 4):

`Paint()` is called whenever the component needs to repaint itself for any reason.  For example, if another window is moved over your component and then is moved away.  `Invalidate()` is merely a manually request to trigger a repaint.  You should not be trying to limit when `Paint()` is called, that is not your responsibility.  Your responsibility is to paint your component whenever a paint is requested.

That being said, `Paint()` should only be called when a real repaint is actually warranted. If your `Paint()` is getting called excessively, then you are doing something wrong.  Either your `Paint()` code is doing something it should not be doing, or code outside of your `Paint()` is calling `Invalidate()`/`Refresh()` too often.  Hard to say for sure since you did not show any of your actual code.